# What's the status of a convert whose father is Jewish? Is he unrelated to his biological father like every other Ger?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

If a Jewish man had a son from a non-Jewish woman, and this son later converted to Judaism, what's the halacha regarding his relationship with his biological father. A convert is כקטן שנולד and unrelated to his parents, but is that the case when his father is Jewish? Will he inherit his father? If his father was a rebbe, will this convert be next in line???

Comment: I know there are converts allowed to call themselves, say, ben Yaakov, if Yaakov is their father's name.  This may imply that their father is recognized as such.

Comment: I don't think the hereditary Rebbe titles have any halachic basis

Comment: I once read it in the Encyclopedia Judaica, that someone whose father is Jewish and then converts, he is eligible to be king of Yisrael, because it is written, From your brethren you shall appoint a king. If I'm not mistaken the reason is the unnecessary "from your brethren" comes to teach that he is eligible for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mishneh Torah (Issurei biah, 12:7)
states that there is no relation even prior to the child's conversion

> שֶׁהַבֵּן מִן הָעֶרְוָה בְּנוֹ הוּא לְכָל דָּבָר וּבִכְלַל יִשְׂרָאֵל נֶחְשָׁב אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא מַמְזֵר וְהַבֵּן מִן הַכּוּתִית אֵינוֹ בְּנוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים ז':ד') כִּי יָסִיר אֶת בִּנְךָ מֵאַחֲרַי מֵסִיר אוֹתוֹ מִלִּהְיוֹת אַחֲרֵי ה':
>
> For a child conceived from any other forbidden sexual union, is [the father's] son with regard to all matters and is considered a member of the Jewish people, even if he is a mamzer. A son conceived by a gentile woman, by contrast, is not considered his son. [This is derived from Deuteronomy 7:4:] "For he shall sway your son away from following Me." She turns him away from being one of those who follow God.